# How adding silvermine video quality selector when using videoJs and lightGallery

Tags: javascript, video, video.js, lightgallery

how can I add video quality selector to videojs player when Iam using lightGallery video gallery
here is my config for the lightGallery

```
const dynamicGalleryVideo = window.lightGallery($dynamicGalleryVideo, {
  dynamic: true,
  download: false,
  plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail, lgVideo],
  videojs: true,
  videojsOptions: {
    muted: false,
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    autoplayFirstVideo: false,
  },
  dynamicEl: [
    {
      video: {
        source: [
          {
            src: "https://blissful-noether-fohw-yyre.storage.iran.liara.space/video/Video.mp4",
            type: "video/mp4",
          },
        ]
}
}
  ],
});
```

#### Edit

I tried to use **Silvermine** package base on their [document](https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-quality-selector) but I couldn't use it with my lightGallery config as you can see above. how can I use silvermine , videojs and lighGallery together? consider that I am using a **dynamic** lightGallery so there is no  tag or any container at first in my html

Comment: You might need to use this plugin https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-quality-selector

Comment: thanks for your answer I tried a lot but because my lightgalley is dynamic and there is no <video> tag in my html I couldnt use silvermine, videojs and lightgalley together . could you help me how can I use silvermine for my above code ?